# ExtJS 3.4 | Create dynamically Tabs from Store-Result

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs, store, extjs3

Is it possible to create a tabbed-panel from a store result?

For example, the result of the store has two id's and for each id a tab should be created or the result has five ids then should the panel has 5 taps.

Is that possible and if there an example?

Thanks and Regards
hugi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example i made for you: It's Ext 4.2 but it should work for 3.4 too (fingers crossed): https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/so8

--- Update ---

Ext 3.4 example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/sr0

Comment: It was so easy to switch to 3.4 in that fiddle to see that it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because Ext 3.4 don't know Ext.Application which has nothing to do with the example itself...

Comment: Not only because of that, I'm afraid, I tested it beyond removing `Ext.Application`. Your answer would be much better if you 1) Provided it for Ext JS 3 in the first place; 2) Tested it rather than crossing fingers.

Comment: Why you aren't posting the "correct" answer then? Anyways, i've updated the initial post with an Ext 3.4 example.

Comment: Hey Tyr, the Example which you had posted in  in Ext 3.4 helped me. Thx for your help. Regards, chris